# Invalid XML entity references from Jekyll

Tags: html, ruby, xml, jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

I'm using [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com) on [GitHub Pages](http://pages.github.com) to run [my blog](http://blog.ploeh.dk).

It seems as though Jekyll (semi-)randomly incorrectly XML escapes an XML special character as `&tt;`.

As an example, in the current version of [the RSS feed](http://blog.ploeh.dk/rss.xml), this source XML

```
</p>
<p>
```

in *a single place* becomes

```
&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&tt;
```

but it should have been

```
&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
```

`&tt;` is an invalid XML entity reference, so some XML parsers choke on that and refuse to go on.

At first I suspected an invisible, invalid character at that place in the source, but as far as I can tell, this isn't the case. What's more is that this behaviour doesn't seem to be consistent:

The RSS feed currently has 7 such errors, of which the above is the first. However, the current [Atom feed](http://blog.ploeh.dk/atom.xml) has only 5 such errors, and *they are not in the same places*. It's not only `<p>` tags that are affected, but other tags as well (e.g. `<ul>` tags should always be escaped as `&lt;ul&gt;`, but is in a single place instead escaped as `&tt;ul&gt;`).

Furthermore, when I run

> jekyll serve -w

on my local machine, I still see the same *type* of error, but not in the same places.

The HTML is XML escaped like this:

```
{{ post.content | xml_escape }}
```

Why does this happen, and what can I do about it?

Comment: This looks like a bug in [Jekyll::Filters#xml_escape](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/filters.rb#L85), more specifically in [CGI::escapeHTML("string")](http://rdoc.sourceforge.net/rd/doc/classes/CGI.html).

Answer (score 3):

The only thing `xml_escape` does is call [`CGI::escapeHTML`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escapeHTML), which replaces certain characters with their counterparts. If the bug is present in Jekyll, it's only because it's present in your version of Ruby's CGI module.